# Empty backbone collection/model at working API?

Tags: backbone.js

i try to fetch a record of a rails-api (same host) into my backbone collection. i have the following code:

```
// Models

App.GeeksModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: "/geeks",
  idAttribute: "id"
});

// Collections

App.GeeksCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: "/geeks",
  model: App.GeeksModel
});
```

in my router i have the following

```
// Router

App.GeekRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "": "index"
  },
  initialize: function() {
    console.log("router - init");
  },
  index: function() {
    console.log("route - index");
    var geekCollection = new App.GeeksCollection();
    var mapView = new App.GeeksMapView({ el: $("#foo"), model: geekCollection });
    geekCollection.fetch();
  }
});
```

when browsing the url, the view loads correctly and at the server i see, that one entry is fetched from the database. but as soon as i check the model length in my view using

```
this.model.length
```

the collection is empty... any advice on this?

thanks

**EDIT 1:**

when changing the index router method to

```
var mapView = new App.GeeksMapView({ el: $("#map"), collection: geekCollection });
```

and e.g. check for the collection length in the views intialize method

```
  ...
  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
    console.log(this.collection.length);
  },
  ...
```

it retunes 0 as well... so nothing changed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to do `collection.length` or if accessing from the model - each model holds reference to collection in which it was created `model.collection.length` - if `this` is referencing to collection doing just `this.length` should be enough, if it's a model then `this.collection.length` will do it for you.

Models have no property length so should always be undefined unless you define it yourself.

Comment: but calling geekCollection.length in the router returns 0 as well?

Comment: the problem is that every time you access index route you create the collection again and its previous states gets lost. Also
`new App.GeeksMapView({ el: $("#foo"), model: geekCollection });` <- you should pass collection as collection not a model

Comment: where exactly do you do the length check?

Comment: by the time the fetch asynchronous request is resolved, the console log already fired as it fires during initialization. If you want to do something after the fetch returns you need to listen to `reset` event on the collection (in initialize add `this.collection.on('reset', this.onCollectionReset, this)`) and add a onCollectionReset method in the view - put the console.log there and you should have your resource available for manipulation - like rendering views/data

Comment: Try to read bit more about how ajax/async requests work seems like you could catch up on this topic a bit :) Backbone model and collection fetch methods are pretty much wrappers for jquery ajax method so getting to know jquery ajax api better will benefit your backbone development as well :) happy to be of help and enjoy backbone!